# Bloomberg access from publishing platforms such as Posit Connect

Tags: data, bloomberg

It is easy to download Bloomberg data in Python or R using their **blpapi** API. The only requirement is that one is logged on the local Bloomberg terminal.

We often find ourselves working on publishing platforms such as Posit Connect or Anaconda Enterprise. Do you know if it possible to download Bloomberg data there? The issue is that these platforms usually run on external servers, where a user doesn't have access to his/her local Bloomberg terminal.

But do you know of any solution that allows for this?

Answer (score 3):

There is a reason why you need to be logged on the bloomberg terminal - it is a desktop solution. As such, you are not allowed to share / distribute or use your data on an enterprise level or with other user.

If you require this, there are specific data license solutions as well as the so called Server API ([SAPI](https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/product/server-api/)) offering. I think the latter is still quite limited with regards to sharing data. As Bob Jansen suggested, it is best to get in touch with BBG directly.

Side remark; technically R is not supported by Bloomberg's API directly. Rblapi is a third party interface that connect to the C++ API Bloomberg offers.

Answer (score 1):

Can you run a local proxy that has access to Bloomberg and access that from Posit or Anaconda.

However, you need to check your contract with Bloomberg: Is what you’re trying to do even allowed? Maybe it’s best to get on the phone with them and figure out what is possible. I don’t think you’ll be the first to ask.